# Import different openapi.json file to spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have custom openapi.json file and empty spring boot app. When I start the app I want it to import that file and show it in swagger-ui URL.

I couldn't find how to do it. All answers were how to generate openapi.json file from code. But my task is opposite.